# Can I send BNB and BEP20 token in the same web3 sendTransaction?

Tags: web3js, wallets, javascript, binance, sendtransaction

I'm trying to develop a javascript function to send BNB and a BEP20 token, at the same time, in one transaction, with web3.

let decimals = web3.utils.toBN(18);
let bnb_amount = web3.utils.toBN(bnbinput);
let bep20_amount = web3.utils.toBN(bep20input);

```
  // Get BEP20 Token contract instance
  let contract = new web3.eth.Contract(minABI, tokenAddress);

  // calculate token amount
  let bnb_value = web3.utils.toWei("1", "ether");
  let bep20_value = bep20_amount.mul(web3.utils.toBN(10).pow(decimals));
```

It works if I only try to **send BNB, without the tokens (msg.value & no msg.data)**

```
var rawTransaction = {
        "from": fromAddress,
        "to": toAddress,
        "value": bnb_value,
        "chainId": web3.utils.toHex(97)
      };

      web3.eth.sendTransaction(rawTransaction, function(log) {
        console.log(log)
      })
```

It also works if I only try to **send tokens, without BNB (msg.data & no msg.value)**

```
var rawTransaction = {
        "from": fromAddress,
        "to": toAddress,
        "data": contract.methods.transfer(toAddress, bep20_value).send({from: fromAddress}),
        "chainId": web3.utils.toHex(97)
      };

      web3.eth.sendTransaction(rawTransaction, function(log) {
        console.log(log)
      })
```

...but **it don't work if I try to put everything together**. Any idea?

*My complete code is the following (not working):*

```
var rawTransaction = {
        "from": fromAddress,
        "to": toAddress,
        "value": bnb_value,
        "data": contract.methods.transfer(toAddress, bep20_value).send({from: fromAddress}),
        "chainId": web3.utils.toHex(97)
      };

      web3.eth.sendTransaction(rawTransaction, function(log) {
        console.log(log)
      })
```

Is there any rule that states that is not possible to set msg.data and msg.value in a web3.eth.sendTransaction()?

Thanks

Comment: Anybody? I do not find a clear way to proceed.